# show hide div jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a show hide div function for my website. But I have one problem with multiple show hide button. So the problem is that when I click show button in container div then all blue div showing automatically.

You can see a [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/hfCLx).

**HTML**:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="div">
    <div id="hidediv">Hide</div>
  </div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div id="showdiv">Show</div>
  
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="div">
    <div id="hidediv">Hide</div>
  </div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div id="showdiv">Show</div>      
</div>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#hidediv").hide();
    $('#showdiv').click(function() {
        $('.div').toggle("slide");
        $("#showdiv").hide();
        $("#hidediv").show();
            
    });
    $('#hidediv').click(function() {
        $('.div').toggle("slide");
        $("#hidediv").hide();
        $("#showdiv").show();                
    });    
});
```

When the user clicks show button in container show div, then I only want to show this div.
I hope you can understand me.

Comment: A valid HTML page will never had a duplicated ID... Make different IDs and Functions for each container

Comment: @artur99 I do not know how to do it. Please could you help.

Comment: And use `.siblings` and similar jQ methonds to reach certain elements.

Comment: You can use classes instead of IDs, huh?

Comment: Use classes instead with child parent css method.

Comment: @simplename, like that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you should use classes instead of id. Fixed HTML becomes:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="div">
        <div class="hidediv">Hide</div>
    </div>
    <div class="test"></div>
    <div class="showdiv">Show</div>
</div>
```

and so on. This is the most flexible approach, because now you can add as many collapsible containers as you need without need to change JS code.

Javascript code then can be (with `on` method for more effective event handling):

```
$('.container').on('click', '.showdiv', function(e) {
    var $container = e.delegateTarget;
    $('.div', $container).toggle('slide');
    $('.showdiv', $container).hide();
    $('.hidediv', $container).show();
})
.on('click', '.hidediv', function(e) {
    var $container = e.delegateTarget;
    $('.div', $container).toggle("slide");
    $(".hidediv", $container).hide();
    $(".showdiv", $container).show();
});
```

#### Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/1j32cwLg/

Comment: why classes instead of ids?

Comment: @DustinAngeletti ids needs to be unique. With classes this code is way more flexible (you can add more containers, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Different ids is a good option but if you really don't want that or maybe there are lots of divs use  the following:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="hidediv">Hide</div>
  <div class="showdiv">Show</div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="container">
    <div class="hidediv">Hide</div>
  <div class="showdiv">Show</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $(".hidediv").hide();
        $('.showdiv').click(function() {
                $(this).hide();
 $(this).parent(".container").children(".hidediv").show();

        });
     $('.hidediv').click(function() {
                $(this).hide();
      $(this).parent(".container").children(".showdiv").show();

        });

    });
```

Comment: Thank you for a different answer.

Answer (score -1):

Make different IDs and Functions for each container like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="div">
    <div id="hidediv">Hide</div>
  </div>
  <div class="test"></div>
  <div id="showdiv">Show</div>

</div>
<div class="container2">
  <div class="div2">
    <div id="hidediv2">Hide</div>
  </div>
  <div class="test2"></div>
  <div id="showdiv2">Show</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
       //function for first container
        $("#hidediv").hide();
        $('#showdiv').click(function() {
                $('.div').toggle("slide");
                $("#showdiv").hide();
                $("#hidediv").show();

        });
     $('#hidediv').click(function() {
                $('.div').toggle("slide");
                $("#hidediv").hide();
                $("#showdiv").show();

        });
    //for second container
       $("#hidediv2").hide();
        $('#showdiv2').click(function() {
                $('.div2').toggle("slide");
                $("#showdiv2").hide();
                $("#hidediv2").show();

        });
     $('#hidediv2').click(function() {
                $('.div2').toggle("slide");
                $("#hidediv2").hide();
                $("#showdiv2").show();

        });
    });
```

CSS:

```
.container, .container2 {
  margin-top:40px;
  width:630px;
  height:190px;
  margin:0px auto;
  border:1px solid #d8dbdf;
}
.test,.test2 {
  float:left;
  width:250px;
  height:190px;
  background-color:red;
}
.div, .div2{
  float:left;
  width:630px;
  height:190px;
  background-color:blue;
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
}
#hidediv, #hidediv2{
  background:red;
}
```

**Exaple here: http://jsfiddle.net/usqeyckd/**

Comment: Thanks for your respond (I know this). But this is not solution. because of if `.div` will be twenty or fifty times what should i do on that time.