# Show/Hide divs with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

First off, there's are many questions similar to mine but I haven't found an answer I've been able to use yet. I have a page that shows a login form when you enter. I also have a register form that I want hidden. With a click I want the login form replaced with the register form.

I've tried this code that I found and with a little help this could work, it has a nice smooth transition but it shows both elements from the start.

```js
$(function() {
  $('a').click(function() {
    div = $(this).attr('href'); //grab #one, #two which correspond to the div id we're targeting
    paragraph = $(div); //store each div in a variable for later use        
    $('#two').hide();
    $('div').hide('grey-bg'); //remove any greyed backgrounds
    $(paragraph).show('grey-bg'); //add grey background to clicked element
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#one {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#two {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.grey-bg {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#one">First Link</a><br />
<a href="#two">Second Link</a>

<div id="one">
  This is the first paragraph.
</div>

<div id="two">
  This is the second paragraph.
</div>
```

You can see it working here: https://codepen.io/raazxplorer/pen/rVKzNp

All I have done with this is changed removeClass and toggleClass to hide/show.

Comment: Just put `display: none` in the CSS of the one you want to hide on load

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery- Hide div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928275/jquery-hide-div)

Comment: Or [show hide div jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25714725/show-hide-div-jquery)

Comment: Or any one of these [google results](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+hide+div+with+jquery&oq=stackoverflow+hide+div+with+jquery&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0j69i64.4903j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)...

Answer (score 2):

add   `display:none;` in `#two`

```
#two {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display:none;
}
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('a').click(function() {
    div = $(this).attr('href'); //grab #one, #two which correspond to the div id we're targeting
    paragraph = $(div); //store each div in a variable for later use        
    $('#two').hide();
    $('div').hide('grey-bg'); //remove any greyed backgrounds
    $(paragraph).show('grey-bg'); //add grey background to clicked element
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#one {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

#two {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display:none;
}

.grey-bg {
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#one">First Link</a><br />
<a href="#two">Second Link</a>

<div id="one">
  This is the first paragraph.
</div>

<div id="two">
  This is the second paragraph.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Hide one of the `div` on page load.

What you need is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#two").hide();
});
```

[Read more about (document).ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

I made a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/embjh1qp/), i did not put the `(document).ready()` part in it because its not necessary in JSFiddle.

But you can add it above `$("#two").hide();` if you wish. It will also work.